# Is it possible to declare variables in a constructor [Java]

Tags: java, variables, constructor, declare

I have been tasked to declare variables in a constructor but I am not sure how I can go about with this. The request states:

"In the constructor, create the Startrek Asteroids Resort given in the Appendix(see below)"

**Lucozade,3,10

Fanta,5,2

Sprite,1,100

Coco,1,1**

And here is my constructor:

```
public Asteroid(String nam, int rat, int cap)
{
    name = nam;
    rating = rat;
    capacity = cap;
}
```

I had considered creating a text file and creating a method to read the data but I'm not sure if this is what they want.

Comment: I think you need to ask a more specific question. The instructions given are unclear and are open to a lot of interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the parameters that are passed in you can just have variables that are declared in your class before hand and save them to these variables.

```
public class Asteroid {
    private String name;
    private int rat;
    private int cap;

    public Asteroid(String name, int rat, int cap) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rat = rat;
        this.cap = cap;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to read the saved parameters out and later modify the initial set values, create public setter and getter methods as well.

Comment: I was confused as to whether they want me to create the Asteroids in the constructor itself. Is there a way to actually create them in the constructor ?

Comment: In this case the whole class is 1 Asteroid Resort itself. I was going under the assumption that Lucozade,3,10 would mean the Asteroid Resort is named Lucozade and has rating of 3 and capacity of 10.

Comment: So its not possible to create the instance of lucozade in the constructor ?

Comment: The instance of lucozade would be created when you call `Asteroid Lucozade = Asteroid("Lucozade", 3, 10);` so this Asteroid variable Lucozade essentially would be lucozade.